# JSF 2.0: How present a 'stand by' message using AJAX?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

i would like to know how i could present a message where after the client filled a form and pressed a button 'Send message ', a message 'Wait while we send your message' could appear to him and then after present 'Message delivered', something like that.

If i could show some icon i think it would be cool too =)

I try this for now:

```
public void sendMessage() {
    // .. my programming logic
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, null, "Message Delivered");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}
```

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is pretty easy using the ajax status indicator of JSF2 component libraries (such as the Richfaces component [a4j:status](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=status&skin=blueSky))

If you want to build this yourself, Jim Driscoll has a blog post on [how to create an ajax status indicator](http://jamesgdriscoll.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/busy-status-indicator-with-jsf-2/) with vanilla jsf2, and a little javascript.

One of the nice things about the a4j:stataus components, is that it can be nested within a component, to provide status updates tailored for that component.  You would then send your message in an action method of a backing bean, initiated with an ajax call.

Comment: Thanks Brian, but i thought there's was a simple way to that, e.g:
change my cursor to 'wait', than back to normal when the request it's complete, got it ?